# Настройка нескольких конфигураций ASP.NET MVC в Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-mvc

Захотел создать отдельную конфигурацию, чтобы получалась отдельная сборка со своим конфигом (чтобы строка подключения SQL Server была своя). То есть, в диспетчере конфигураций создал новую (**Deploy**) и в контекстном меню **Web.config** (в солюшн эксплорере) сделал "*Добавить преобразование конфигурации*". И у меня появился **Web.Deploy.config**. Если в контекстном меню **Web.Deploy.config** нажать "*Просмотреть изменения для **Web.Deploy.config***", то они есть, он отличается от корневого **Web.config**. Пока все путем. Но при запуске (через Visual Studio) приложения эти изменения не применяются, конфигом остается корневой **Web.config** (происходит попытка использовать не ту строку подкючения, которая в **Web.Deploy.config**, а вообще какую-то... дефолтную видимо (в **Web.config** строка подключения не указана)). В папке с проектом есть **\bin** и **\obj**. В **\bin** просто лежат dll, в **\obj** есть по папке для каждой конфигурации, в которых есть **ProjectName.csproj.App.config**, который идентичен корневому **Web.config**.

Вопрос: как достичь появления сборок для каждой конфигурации проекта? Куда они должны сохраняться?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказывается, Visual Studio при запуске использует исключительно корневой **Web.config**, в независимости от выбранной конфигурации. При публикации же проекта используются уже преобразованный **Web.config**, в зависимости от выбранной при публикации конфигурации. Таким образом, средствами Visual Studio, этого достичь нельзя. Возможно, конфигурируя MSBuild ($(ProjectName).csproj), такого удастся добиться.